# JQuery/CSS with Internet Explorer 8 does not show the background-image

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer-8

I have the following code in JQuery (JavaScript), and works fine in Chrome, Safari and Firefox. However, it does not show them in Internet Explorer 8. What could be possibly wrong? I am using 960gs as CSS framework.

```
// JavaScript
var site_root = "http://localhost:8080";

var banner = new Array();

banner[1] = site_root + "/images/banner-1.png";
banner[2] = site_root + "/images/banner-2.png";
banner[3] = site_root + "/images/banner-3.png";
banner[4] = site_root + "/images/banner-4.png";
banner[5] = site_root + "/images/banner-5.png";
banner[6] = site_root + "/images/banner-6.png";
var counter = 1;

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#top_banner').hide();
    $('#top_banner').slideDown('slow');

    var timer = setInterval(StepThroughBanners, 5000);

    function StepThroughBanners() {
        var link = "url(" + banner[counter] + ")";
        $('#top_banner').css("background-image", link); 

        if(counter<6) { 
            counter++;
        } else {
            counter = 1;
        }
    }

});
```

Here is my CSS:

```
#top_banner {
    background: #fff;
    background-image: url("../images/banner-1.png");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;

    color: #fff;
    height: 370px;
    padding: 1em;
}
```

**EDIT:** (HTML added)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<head><title><?= $title ?></title>
    <!-- load style framework 960 -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?= base_url(); ?>css/960.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?= base_url(); ?>css/reset.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?= base_url(); ?>css/text.css" />
    <!-- load custom styles -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?= base_url(); ?>css/custom.css" />

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
        <script src="<?= base_url();?>scripts/general.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>


    </head>
        <body>
            <div class="container_16">
                <div id="top_menu" class="grid_16">


        <div class="menu">
                    <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">item 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">item 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">item 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">item 4</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">item 5</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">item 6</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="tool">
                    <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">one &#x25BE;</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">two &#x25BE;</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">three &#x25BE;</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="search">
                        <form>
                        <input type="text" value="search..."></input>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="clear"></div>
            <div id="top_banner" class="grid_16">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="clear"></div>

            <div class="grid_4 mockup">460px</div>
            <div class="grid_4 mockup"><p>460px</p></div>
            <div class="grid_4 mockup"><p>460px</p></div>
            <div class="grid_4 mockup">460px</div>

            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you post your HTML please?

Comment: Thank you all so much for your incredible help... Here comes the facepalm - I tested this site on my Windows box - over my home network... site_root, well you can guess... Yes, I deserve the fire stake. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Works fine for me](http://jsfiddle.net/Shef/kZhTn/). It just takes time for the first time the images are loaded.

Though you should update this line, just to be sure, from:

```
var link = "url(" + banner[counter] + ")";
```

to

```
var link = "url('" + banner[counter] + "')";
```

Comment: Okay, check your URL structure then. Do the images exist on `http://localhost:8080/images/banner-1.png`, `http://localhost:8080/images/banner-2.png`, `http://localhost:8080/images/banner-3.png`, ... ?

Comment: Try adding your images to [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Shef/kZhTn/), and see if it works there.

Comment: localhosts route to the laptop that is running IE8... which isn't the localhost that serves the images... :) thanks for your incredible help though, and that spiffy online tool (its awesome)

Comment: jsfiddle does not even open for me with IE8

Answer (score 1):

Just a quick guess, but aren't you missing 's when you generate the CSS-property?

You're using

```
var link = "url(" + banner[counter] + ")";
```

what should return a string like `url(mylocation/myfile.jpg)`. Maybe try using

```
var link = "url('" + banner[counter] + "')";
```

instead what should return `url('mylocation/myfile.jpg')`.

Comment: I've tried this - still no resolution - IE does give a status of the download of the image as Done in the statusbar. It is just not displaying the image :(

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything highly unusual with your JavaScript or CSS.  You might consider posting your HTML just in case.  Also, you say the images won't show.  Does the initial image show or is it the case that the images won't rotate?

Have you tried troubleshooting in IE?  Add an alert in StepThroughBanners to be sure it is being called.

Another possibility is that you might need to specify additional CSS properties to get this to render in IE.  Maybe IE's default value for a given property like width, z-index, etc. differs from the other browsers.

You might also check your settings in IE.  Are you running in compatibility mode?

Comment: StepThroughBanners gets called by IE - the HTML is basically a div of 940 px wide (960gs). The initial picture is shown, and the Developer Tools on IE8 don't give anything back. I am not running in CM.